# how to make session storage change value

Tags: javascript, html, session-storage

I am making a website and am new to html and JavaScript I Basically have a video that takes over the whole screen when you first open the site once the video is done it transitions into the home page. I am trying to have it so that you can only view it once per session. My issue is that when ever u switch to another page and come back to the home page u will have to watch the video again. I am using session storage btw. Any help is appreciated

```
<body class="Video" id="Video">
    <div class="video">
        <video id="myVideo" width="500" muted autoplay>
            <source src="video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        </video>
    </div>

    <script>

        var x = document.getElementById('myVideo');
        var i = document.getElementById('Home');
        var header = document.getElementById('header');
        var office = document.getElementById('office');
        var work = document.getElementById('work');
        var info = document.getElementById('info');

        var total = 1;
        var count;
        console.log(total, count);
        if (total !== count) {
            sessionStorage.setItem('isNewSession', 'true');
            console.log(sessionStorage.getItem("isNewSession"))
            
            count = 1;
            console.log(total, count);
        }
        if (sessionStorage.getItem("isNewSession") == 'true') {
            sessionStorage.setItem('isNewSession', 'false');
            console.log(sessionStorage.getItem("isNewSession"))



            i.style.overflow = "hidden";
            header.style.visibility = "visiblie";
            office.style.visibility = "hidden";
            work.style.visibility = "hidden";
            info.style.visibility = "hidden";
            footer.style.visibility = "hidden";


            document.getElementById('myVideo').addEventListener('ended', function (e) {

                x.style.visibility = "hidden";
                i.style.visibility = "visible";



                if (i.style.visibility === "visible") {
                    i.style.overflow = "visible";
                    header.style.visibility = "visible";
                    office.style.visibility = "visible";
                    work.style.visibility = "visible";
                    info.style.visibility = "visible";
                    footer.style.visibility = "visible";
                } else {
                    i.style.visibility = "hidden";
                    header.style.visibility = "visible";
                    office.style.visibility = "hidden";
                    work.style.visibility = "hidden";
                    info.style.visibility = "hidden";
                    footer.style.visibility = "hidden";
                }

            })
        }
        else {
            x.style.visibility = "hidden";
        }
    </script>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

These lines:

```
    var total = 1;
    var count;
    console.log(total, count);
    if (total !== count) {
        sessionStorage.setItem('isNewSession', 'true');
        console.log(sessionStorage.getItem("isNewSession"))
        
        count = 1;
        console.log(total, count);
    }
```

Will always run since `total !== count` initially. Since it always runs, it changes `isNewSession` to `'true'`, which makes the next code block run too. I'm not sure what it's intended to do; if `total` and `count` don't do anything else, you should probably just delete this whole section.

After you delete it, you can change this:

```
    if (sessionStorage.getItem("isNewSession") == 'true') {
```

to

```
    if (sessionStorage.getItem("isNewSession") !== 'false') {
```

In this case, it will run if `sessionStorage` isn't set, or if the value is anything other than `'false'`.

Comment: but if I set the session storage it just keeps resetting back to true so how would I be able to permanently change it

Comment: You're setting it in the next line: `sessionStorage.setItem('isNewSession', 'false')`. If you refresh the page it should stay set.

Comment: Thanks so much guys idk why i didnt think about this